# Difference between Spring DOCTYPE and <beans> tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring there is a XML configuration for bean right?

What is the difference between:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
```

and

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```

Also i'm a bit curious with the difference between `SpringMVC`, `MVC` and just `Spring`

Comment: What is "SpringMVC", "MVC" and "Spring"? Namespaces?

Comment: What do you mean by "Namespaces"?

Comment: XSD documents allow to define namespaces. Each namespace is set of tags. Spring configuration have such namespaces as "task", "mvc", "context" and others. More namespaces you can find in that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174286/spring-xml-namespaces-how-do-i-find-what-are-the-implementing-classes-behind-t.

Comment: If you ask about this terms: Spring is group of frameworks and also core framework of this group (named "context"), SpringMVC is one from this group. Some information about spring framework you can find here: http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework. MVC is design pattern which defines three components of web-applications: model, view and controller. Model is responsible for modelling domain objects, controller handle requests from client and view is responsible for controllers work results representation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Difference is in formats of documents definitions. First is called [DTD](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/), second - [XSD](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/). Both are used to describe possible contents of xml document. DTD is older than XSD. XSD is more flexible and powerful than DTD. More differences you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490583/dtd-or-xml-schema-which-one-is-better).

Comment: So it is mor advisable to use XSD?

Comment: Yes, xsd is more advisable.

Comment: Can you give me links of video tutorials can't find one that have good explanation and clear audio/english.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know such video tutorials. I can only recommend to read book: http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Spring-3-Clarence-Ho/dp/1430241071 It gives broad overview of spring features

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>

<!-- bean definitions here -->

</beans>
```

The equivalent file in the XML Schema-style would be…​

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- bean definitions here -->

</beans>
```

The above Spring XML configuration fragment is boilerplate that you can copy and paste (!) and then plug  definitions into like you have always done.

Differences between an XML Schema Definition (XSD) and Document Type Definition (DTD) include: XML schemas are written in XML while DTD are derived from SGML syntax. XML schemas define datatypes for elements and attributes while DTD doesn't support datatypes. ... XML schemas are extensible while DTD is not extensible.