# are DTDs still used to conform xml?

Tags: javascript, xml, dtd

From what I understand, xml schema has replaced DTDs. Does this mean that it is now outdated and should not be used? I have tried looking at different blogs but could not find anything.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490583/dtd-or-xml-schema-which-one-is-better?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544200/what-is-difference-between-xml-schema-and-dtd?rq=1. There are things that exist in DTD (entities) which are not available in XML Schemas. DTDs also have a very concise syntax which can be simpler to express ideas.

Answer (score 6):

DTDs are still usable, they work as well as they ever did. Some people love them, some people hate them. In the world of international information standards more people are using XSD these days (it has better support for defining fields such as numbers and dates), but for document design, there are lots of enthusiasts who prefer to do things the old way.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to share an XML format that conforms in a specific way, then a DTD is the way to go. I have had to write and create DTD's in the past for applications and they are very useful especially when you want others to import data in XML in a specific way; it gives them a way to know if their data conforms with how you expect to read it.